# Insert server-side rendered HTML via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which changes frequently. I plan to fetch the new pre-rendered table from the server and switch it with the old table via Javascript.

Is this a terrible idea?

How would I go about it?

Comment: It's a server-side-rendered webapp by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a terrible idea, but you can do better, the issue here is that you are sending an html output and not the actual data.

A better alternative would be to build an endpoint that gives you the actual data without the html, and then when you retrieve that data you update the views as needed, the advantages of this approach are:

- You are only sending the data, and no unnecessary html, and so bundle size will be smaller, this will make the servers cost less, and front end will be able to interact with the data faster
- sending an html means that you are tying this data to one type of a client, in this case this will be a browser, but what if later u decided to add mobiles, and other types of clients. When sending only data, later you can consume this endpoint from any client you want
- sending only data will make it easier to make the client interact smarter with the data, and so optimising the user experience, for example if u notice that more data was added, and these data are at the end of the table, and u have table pagination, u can add these to the end of the table without disturbing the user. however if this was html you would need to replace the whole content, and the user will be disturbed.
- finally, sending only data will make it easier to handle caching at both front-end and back-end, since you are doing caching on top of one layer (data) instead of two (data inside html)

Not everything i said here will apply to your use case, however i thought these are things u should consider. Other than that your approach will still work.

Comment: Thanks for your great and comprehensive answer. What I didn't make clear is that my app is a server-side rendered webapp so I've already made the decision to serve HTML.  I've added this info to my original question to make it clearer.